# monitoring CPU time with "/proc/stat"

Tags: cpu, time

I must have some problems understanding "/proc/stat". In the attached calc sheet (an image in fact, because I could not add a sheet), I have recorded some collected "/proc/stat" with a 2 seconds delay (yellow columns show the time of day and the exact time between two scans, blue columns show the coreresponding first line of "/proc/stat").
In the white columns I perform some computations.
In column Q I add all 10 cpu times and expect a result of 100%. This is not the case.
Where does the problem come from ?
Thanks for your help.
[image: copy of calc sheet]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text. Post some data here as *text*, instead.

Answer (score 2):

So the best way to look at this is the cumulative stats for all the CPUs. I just ran the following:

```
cat /proc/stat | grep "cpu "; sleep 1; cat /proc/stat | grep "cpu "
cpu  72793 633 14979 2271004 2783 0 517 0 0 0
cpu  72794 633 14980 2271403 2783 0 518 0 0 0
```

The change between the two sets of results is the number of USER_HZ consumed.  So, I get

user: 72794 - 72793 = 1

nice:  633 - 633 = 0

system: 14980 - 14979 = 1

idle: 2271403 - 2271004 = 399

iowait: 2783 - 2783 = 0

irq: 0 - 0 = 0

softirq: 518 - 517 = 1

steal: 0 - 0 = 0

guest: 0 - 0 = 0

guest_nice: 0 - 0 = 0

So the total USER_HZ consumed is 1 + 0 + 1 + 399 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 0 = 402.  This is for a 4 thread machine, so that comes to ~100.5 USER_HZ per CPU, which is about right for some statistical sampling on a 100Hz jiffy clock. A longer sample period will lead to a closer result to the jiffy clock rate.

You can do the same for all the n CPUs in a system, cpu0.. CPUn-1.  Just compute the delta of the stats between each sample period, sum up the deltas and it will invariably be roughly equal to the number of CPUs x jiffy clock rate.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I misunderstood the way it was to be computed

Comment: No problem. If this fixes your issue then please indicate so on the question